# Suppose $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is closed and $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is compact. Show that every open cover of $E\cap K$ has a finite subcover

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Since K is compact, any subset of K, for example, $E\cap K\subseteq K$ must also be compact. I want to illustrate this point using open covers only. (Showing that every open cover has a finite subcover)

Let $U$ be an open cover of $E\cap K$

Consider $U\cup (\mathbb{R}\backslash E)$

We can see that $U\cup (\mathbb{R}\backslash E)$ covers all of K (since E and K are complements in $\mathbb{R}$)

Now, I know what I have to do next is to use the open cover of K,  $U\cup (\mathbb{R}\backslash E)$, as well as the fact that $E\cap K$ is compact to construct an arbitrary open cover and its finite subcover.

But I'm not sure of my work. Tell me what you think.

---

$U$ is an open cover of $E\cap K$

Pick $n \in \mathbb{N}$

$U_n = \cup^{n}_{i=1}Ui$ is a finite subcover of $U$

Thus, every open cover of $E\cap K$ has a finite subcover

---

This seems too obvious to me to be true, however.

Plus it fails to use the complement that I constructed

Comment: Seems like you are using the definition of compactness and not the H-B theorem.  Is your title wrong?

Comment: @Randall Maybe my choice of words was poor. I really just want to show that every open cover of $E\cap K$ has a finite subcover

Comment: @Randall I'm stuck in the sense that the open cover I constructed seems unsupported logically. That is, I know that it works, but I don't know how to provide evidence that it works

Comment: Your $U$ should be a family of subsets of the real line, so what does $U \cup (\mathbb{R}-E)$ mean?

Comment: Not sure to understand the question. If $E$ is closed and $K$ is compact, then $E \cap K$ is compact, so of course every open cover of $E \cap K$ has a finite subcover.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe  my guess is that OP wants a proof using only open covers and nothing else, but I'm not 100%.

Comment: @Randall, Since E and K are complements on the real line, and since $U$ is an open cover of $E\cap K$, then we can safely say that $U\cup(\mathbb{R}\backslash E)$ is an open cover of all of K

Comment: @TheSilverDoe, Randall is right: I want a proof using only open covers

Comment: @user811112  you likely mean $\bigcup_{i \in I} U_i \cup (\mathbb{R}-E)$ where $U = \{U_i \mid i \in I\}$.

Comment: @Randall Is that all I need to show that every open cover has a finite subcover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Write $F=E\cap K$. Let $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in A}$ be an open cover of $F\subset K$. Then $\{U_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in A}$, along with $F^c$, provides an open cover of $K$. Since $K$ is compact...

Comment: What is meant by $F^c$? I'm not familiar with that notation, sorry

Comment: @user811112 the complement of $F$.

Comment: I need to show that every open cover has a finite subcover though. Does @zugzug explanation provide that?

Comment: You are trying to come with a finite number of open sets from the arbitrary open cover $\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in A}$. When you include $F^c$, you now have an open cover of $K$. By compactness of $K$, how can you reduce this open cover to a finite subcover and why does a finite subcover of $F$ exist?