# E is closed. K is compact. Show that every open cover of $E\cap K$ has a finite subcover

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let me know what you think

(By the way, we are assuming our universal set to be $\mathbb{R}$)

---

*Proof*

Let $U$ be an open cover of $E\cap K$

$U\cup(\mathbb{R}\backslash E)$ is an open cover of K

Since K is compact $U\cup (\mathbb{R} \backslash E)$ has a finite subcover

Choose $U_n=U_1\cup U_2\cup ...\cup U_n$ as a finite subcover of $U\cup(\mathbb{R}\backslash E)$

So $K \subseteq U_n \subseteq U\cup(\mathbb{R}\backslash E)$

But also note that $E\cap K \subseteq K$

Then, putting it altogether, we have

$E\cap K \subseteq K \subseteq U_n \subseteq U\cup(\mathbb{R} \backslash E)$

$E \cap K \subseteq U_n$

Thus $E \cap K$ is compact

---

But this doesn't seem to tell me that $U$ has a finite subcover.

If $U$ doesn't have a finite subcover, then my argument is null.

Any advice on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What's the difference between this and yesterday's question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suppose $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is closed and $K\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is compact. Show that every open cover of $E\cap K$ has a finite subcover](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3894179/suppose-e-subseteq-mathbbr-is-closed-and-k-subseteq-mathbbr-is-compact)

Comment: A cover of a set $S$ is a collection of sets whose union admits $S$ as a subset. Your notation confuses open covers and opens sets.

Comment: @Randall, in this version, I'm constructing a finite subcover from $U\cup (\mathbb{R } \backslash E)$ whereas yesterday, I tried to construct a finite subcover from $U$ out of thin air.

Comment: I need to figure out how to go from the fact that $U \cup \mathbb{R} \backslash E$ has a finite subcover and that $E \cap K \subseteq K $ to showing that $U$ has a finite subcover

Comment: "Since $E$ and $K$ are complements in $\mathbb{R}$..." : Why are these sets complements? Is this an unstated hypothesis?

Comment: @MPW  it is specifically assumed by the professor. It’s not officially the case. It’s just an arbitrary assumption

Comment: @MPW nevermind, I fixed it. They’re not complements. You’re right